# "RpcAsync.h" header file not being read, in which I have put in order for recognizing AnsiString in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++

This is my first time working with header files, and I have a source code and I'm trying to include `RpcAsync.h` file and written in the beginning of my source file.

However Visual Studio is not recognizing the header file for AnsiString. I am able to see AnsiString definitions in `RpcASync.h` .

It throws an error saying :

```
1   IntelliSense: identifier "AnsiString" is undefined.
```

Comment: Did you include the file in the solution?

Comment: Do you need to use `AnsiString`?  Can you use `std::string` instead?

Comment: Whatever *real* problem you have, you will never solve it with rpcasync.h

Answer (score 0):

I did include the file in the solution. and I did used std::string it doesn't serve the purpose.
AnsiString has been declared in header file RpcASync.h as :

typedef struct tagRPC_EE_INFO_PARAM
{ 
    union
        {
        LPSTR AnsiString;
        } u;
}

In CPP file I have included RpcASync.h header file and tried to access AnsiString as a parameter in function as follows

bool FindRunningProcess(AnsiString process) 
{

```
 AnsiString compare;
     if (pe32.szExeFile == process) {
            procRunning = true;
        } else {
            // loop through all running processes looking for process
            while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32)) { 
                // Set to an AnsiString instead of Char[] to make compare                  easier
                compare = pe32.szExeFile;
                if (compare == process) {
                    // if found process is running, set to true and break from loop
                    procRunning = true;
                    break;
```

---

}

but when I compile it throws an error - 
 IntelliSense: identifier "AnsiString" is undefined.

Note : pe32.szExeFile is of WCHAR , So I am using process as AnsiString